# Installing hadoop is trouble

Tags: hadoop

[image]

Have some  problem when I start `hadoop`. `Namenode` and `Datanode` can't operate.
Help me...

Comment: I doubt this is a programming question, but anyway - do you have a space in front of hdfs?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the namenode address definition has a white space before it. Make sure there are no spaces or tabs or new lines before it in your `hdfs-site.xml`. You probably have something like this:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>
      hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
...
```

But it should look like this:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
...
```